# Decision trees. Choosing thresholds to split objects

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

If I understand [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#mathematical-formulation) correctly, a set of objects (which are arrays of features) is presented and we need to split it into 2 subsets. To do that we compare some feature x<sub>j</sub> to a threshold t<sub>m</sub> (t<sub>m</sub> is the threshold at m node). We use an impurity function H() to find the best way to split the objects. But how do we choose the values of t<sub>m</sub> and which feature should be compared to the thresholds? I mean, there is an infinite number of ways we can choose t<sub>m</sub> so we can't just compute H() function for each possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Page 18 of these [slides](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse446/13sp/slides/decision-trees-boosting-annotated.pdf), two methods are introduced to choose the splitting threshold for a numerical attribute X.

**Method 1:**

- Sort data according to X into {x_1, ..., x_m}
- Consider split points of the form x_i + (x_{i+1} - x_i)/2

**Method 2:**

Suppose X is a real-value variable

- Define IG(Y|X:t) as H(Y) - H(Y|X:t)
- Define H(Y|X:t) = H(Y|X < t) P(X < t) + H(Y|X >= t) P(X >= t)

  - IG(Y|X:t) is the information gain for predicting Y if all you
    know is whether X is greater than or less than t
- Then define IG^*(Y|X) = max_t IG(Y|X:t)
- For each real-valued attribute, use IG*(Y|X) for assessing its suitability as a split

*Note, may split on an attribute multiple times,
with different thresholds*

Comment: in method 2: what is the definition of t and what are common ways to set a range of values for t in method 2? Method 1 seems to provide an answer the OP's question, whereas the explanation in Method 2 doesn't seem complete.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an infinite number of ways of choosing t<sub>m</sub>. Given a reasonable range of thresholds a simple implementation might iterate over them, evaluate H() and the feature split that would result in the best split given that impurity measure would be chosen for that split in the decision tree.

Comment: How can I estimate a "reasonable range"?